# Sequence Regression and Sequence Learning

Tags: time-series, machine-learning-model, sequential-pattern-mining

My training data is structured as sequential data in the following format:

[image: Text]

where $n$ represents the $n$th data point in my training data of length $N$, and $m \leq M := M(n)$ represents the $m$th observation in the corresponding sequential data of length $M$ for the $n$th data point.

Some things to additionally note:

- $t_m$ is the timestamp measuring the number of seconds when $x_m$ is observed. This timestamp is always greater than or equal to $0$.
- $x_m$ is currently one-hot encoded identifying the presence of categorical variables in the $m$th observation for the $n$th data point in my training set
- $y_n$ is a real-valued number that maps the sequential data observation to this number for each data point in this training set. The value of $y_n$ is ordinal, indicating that we're looking at some form of regression problem. $y_n \geq 0$ as well.

Given that I tried extensively to look for solutions to the above problem via Google and Stack Overflow, I'm struggling to formulate a model that would generate the mapping from sequential data to nonnegative real-value. Some methods I tried include:

- Many-to-One Recurrent Neural Networks with Variable-Sized Sequential Data inputs
- Translating Sequential Data features to aggregate statistics features (e.g. looking at mean timedeltas between $t_k$ and $t_{k+1}$ for each categorical variable) and use any supervised learning method like random forests to build a regressor model
- [Distribution Regression for Sequential Data](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v130/lemercier21a/lemercier21a.pdf)

What are some strategies and other modeling recommendations I can consider? Ideally, I would like a very minimal example illustrating how this can be implemented in Python if possible (or links containing examples to look at).

Thanks! I have struggled to find a good solution online or any resources that would be well suited for this use case. It's possible that I am unable to uncover good resources for the above models considered, so if there is truly a great minimal example to rely on for one of the bullet points above, I would happily reconsider them too.